# Passing arrays/variables into sendgrid api with php

Tags: php, variables, sendgrid

I have an array of email addresses that I need to iterate through and send an email to using the sendgrid api in php and I'm not sure how to go about it as sendgrid doesn't seem to like variables.

The code I've tried is:

```
$no_contacts = count($contacts);
for ($i=0; $i<$no_contacts; $i+=1){
$contact = $contacts[$i];
$email = new \SendGrid\mail\Mail(); 
    $email->setFrom("examplesender@mail.com", "App Name");
$email->setSubject("Update");
$email->addTo($contact, "Name");
$email->addContent(
    "text/html", $messages[0]
);
$sendgrid = new \SendGrid('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');
try {
    $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
    //print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
    //print_r($response->headers());
    //print $response->body() . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: '. $e->getMessage() ."\n";
}
}
```

Passing $messages[0] works fine however for the addTo section passing $contacts[$i] or $contact doesn't work. I've tried this where $contacts[$i] stores either "examplesreciever@mail.com" or examplereciever@mail.com and both return the following: Fatal error: Uncaught SendGrid\Mail\TypeException: "$emailAddress" must be a valid email address. Got: examplereciever@mail.com

Comment: `var_dump($contact);` and tell us what it contains

Comment: you may have just solved it, it seems to be adding a space at the end, ill try to find out how to remove that now

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the data contained in either $contacts or $messages, however, if `$contacts` is structured correctly, you can use the `addTos()` method, instead of a loop, as in the example below.

```
<?php

use SendGrid\Mail\HtmlContent;

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();
$dotenv->required(['SENDGRID_API_KEY']);

$contacts = [
    'user1@example.org' => 'user 1',
    'user2@example.org' => 'user 2',
];

$messages = [
    'Here is some message content.',
];

$email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail();
$email->setFrom("sender@example.org", "Email Sender");
$email->setSubject("Update");
$email->addTos($contacts);
$email->addContent(new HtmlContent($messages[0]));

$sendgrid = new \SendGrid($_ENV['SENDGRID_API_KEY']);
try {
    $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
    print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: '. $e->getMessage() ."\n";
}
```

Note that `$contacts` is an array of email addresses and user names.

Secondly, if you included your actual SendGrid API key in your example above, make sure that you rotate it **ASAP** so that it can't be abused by malicious actors.

A great way to avoid including confidential data in code is by using a package such as [PHP Dotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv), as I have in the example above. [Check out this short tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/blog/working-with-environment-variables-in-php), if you're keen to learn more about it and setting environment variables in PHP.